# ffmpeg error with frei0r pixeliz0r filter (Duplicated pixel format)

Tags: ffmpeg

I run ffmpeg on Linux(Arch).
I try to run

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf frei0r=pixeliz0r output.mp4
```

I have this error:

```
[Parsed_frei0r_0 @ 0x5585b8093280] Duplicated pixel format
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

I chose `--enable-frei0r` when I compiled.

ffmpeg output:

```
ffmpeg version N-99920-g46e362b765 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-frei0r
```

end of the log when the debug is enabled

```
[Parsed_frei0r_0 @ 0x55e92c387280] name:pixeliz0r author:'Gephex crew' explanation:'Pixelize input image.' color_model:packed32 frei0r_version:1 version:1.0 num_params:2
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55e92c3806c0] Setting 'video_size' to value '640x480'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55e92c3806c0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '13'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55e92c3806c0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/15360'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55e92c3806c0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '0/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55e92c3806c0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '30/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55e92c3806c0] w:640 h:480 pixfmt:yuvj422p tb:1/15360 fr:30/1 sar:0/1
[format @ 0x55e92c381300] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16|nv21|yuv420p10le|yuv422p10le|yuv444p10le|nv20le|gray|gray10le'
[Parsed_frei0r_0 @ 0x55e92c387280] Duplicated pixel format
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[AVIOContext @ 0x55e92c1edf00] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x55e92c1e3a40] Statistics: 70706 bytes read, 2 seeks
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like vf_frei0r was broken by [69f5f6ea](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/69f5f6ea375950b4845b241ee27054bfc8f00343) (or rather, it was always a little bit broken, but now there's a check that makes it fail). You can

1. [File a bug](https://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html).
2. Not run git `HEAD` of ffmpeg — the troublesome commit isn't present in `n4.3.1`, the latest release.

Comment: Thank you so much, I rolled back to [6479f40a](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/6479f40afa3c706ada2e2c0b05de473285d6a926) and it works.